# Installing a Windows O.S from another Windows System

Tags: windows-7

I'm looking for a way to install a Windows O.S from a live running copy of Windows 7 (without rebotting, etc in a different drive) it's even possible? As far I searched there's only entrances to do as always. (booting and install to the drive).

Comment: I would not say that it is not possible, but there is much to consider. (Driver/new Hardware, Files which are in access during copy, ...)

Comment: @Ramhound: Maybe i misunderstood the question. I thought it's about copying a live system to another pc (not about **new installation**).

Comment: @Ramhound there you go. I've just proven you wrong :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is.

Using this utility [NT 6.X Fast Installer](http://reboot.pro/index.php?app=core&module=attach&section=attach&attach_id=10559) and [Get WAIK Tools](http://www.rmprepusb.com/tutorials/getwaiktools/GetWaikTools.7z?attredirects=0&d=1) you are able to create a preinstalled Windows drive.

**Disclaimer: I am not the author of these tools, and any damage that could happen is not my responsibility.**

In case you don't know what you need to do, I have prepared two zip files.

If you want to install Windows 7 32 bit You will need [These Files](http://silocal.info/Windows7_x86.zip)

If you want to install Windows 7 64 bit You will need [These Files](http://silocal.info/Windows7_amd64.zip)

All you need to do  is download the files relating to the edition of Windows you want to install, extract the ZIP, and run installer.bat

The installer will then guide you through the stages to create the drive.

For anyone wanting to see the forum post, it's [here](http://reboot.pro/topic/10126-nt-6x-fast-installer-install-win7-directly-to-usb-external-drive/)

The description of the NT 6.X Fast Installer Follows:

> As you know, stupid setup.exe for nt 6.x (vista/win7/2008/2008 r2) has
>   many limitations:
>
> 1. You can't start install vista/win7 under xp based pe (winpe 1.x) and can't install win7 under win2000
> 2. You can't install win7 directly to USB hard disk
> 3. The stupid setup.exe may put the boot files to a wrong drive when you boot winpe with USB device and there is even no way to choose the
>      boot partition Posted Image
> 4. When you install win7 from winpe, the drive letter of the OS partition will always be C:, no matter which partition you choose.
>
> On the other hand, the fastest way to install nt 6.x is
>   imagex+bcdboot, e.g
>
> ```
> imagex f:\sources\install.wim 5 c:
> bcdboot c:\windows /s c:
> bootsect /nt60 c:
> ```
>
> And no setup.exe is needed.
>
> Based on this, I wrote an "nt 6.x fast installer" which has the
>   following advatages compare to the original M$ setup.exe:
>
> 1. You can install nt 6.x directly from iso file mounted by any kind of virtual drive. And you needn't extract or burn the iso.
> 2. You can directly install nt 6.x from any version winpe and win2000 above windows
> 3. You can install the OS directly onto a USB external hard drive. And no virtual machine, copy tool or complicated "tutorial" is needed.
> 4. You can manually choose which partition is the boot partition.
> 5. You can decide which letter the OS partition will occupy in Win7/2008 R2.
> 6. The install speed is very fast. With this installer, you can install win7 in 11-12 min for 5400rpm notebook hdd, and in less than
>      10min for desktop 7200 hdd (vista needs about 2 min more because of
>      the score evaluation)

Comment: Just to confirm.  This allows somebody to install a Windows installation to a disk, while Windows is running, without restarting the computer?  I can't find any information on the NT 6.x Fast Installer.  I am aware of the other class of tool ( its since been renamed to something else )  I am hesitant to award the reputation for that reason.  Once the question is eligible for a bounty I will award it though.

Comment: yup, I used to use it all the time, until I built a distrib server. This is the link: http://reboot.pro/topic/10126-nt-6x-fast-installer-install-win7-directly-to-usb-external-drive/

Comment: from the authors description: `Based on this, I wrote an "nt 6.x fast installer" which has the following advatages compare to the original M$ setup.exe:
1. You can install nt 6.x directly from iso file mounted by any kind of virtual drive.`

Comment: On restart, Windows will do the first time setup, completely ignoring the fact that it wasn't installed the "official" way.

Comment: I am an idiot for not thinking to simply apply a .wim file to a partition.  Since I was an idiot you get an additional bonus for teaching me something new.  Once this question is eligible I will offer the bounty then issue the award.  I suggest you integrate the description of the program into your answer and also provide the forum topic ( as a way for other people to read about it ).

Comment: xD, we all have days like this. that script is however the easiest way to install windows, including changing the default C: drive letter. I change mine to Z:.

Comment: Most definite +1 for this - will have to read up on it. Kudos to @Ramhound too, for being a true 'scientist' in the face of new evidence. √

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use WinNTSetup which is basically a GUI for this type of thing. 
https://www.softpedia.com/get/System/OS-Enhancements/WinNTSetup.shtml