# Repairing/reinstalling Windows 10 - can I use a recovery disk from another PC?

Tags: windows-10

I have a Windows 10 Home PC (upgraded from Vista through v8 to v10) that will no longer boot into Windows, it goes into "Automatic Repair", and none of the options there help in my case: I tried Reset this PC, System Restore, System Image Recovery, Startup Repair, Startup in Safe Mode, Go back to Previous Version, etc. All failed.

Unfortunately I never created a recovery disk, but I do have access to 2 other Windows 10 Home laptops with internet access. They are from different manufacturers, with different processors and components. To further complicate matters, my broken PC is running Windows 10.0.15063.0, and my two laptops are both running 10.0.14393 (I made it into the recovery console).

So:

1. If I create a USB recovery disk from one of these laptops, can I use it to repair/reinstall the OS on my broken PC? Or are recovery disks specific to the machine they are created on, or to their specific components?
2. If that doesn't work, do I need to create a different type of (generic) Windows 10 USB install media boot disk instead?

I'd prefer to keep/recover my data (from multiple user profiles), but I can recover from an online backup service if necessary.

Comment: You would have to upgrade the installation to 1607 before it would work, but, it will work. just use a Windows 10 1607 Installation disk instead, same exact environment, as the recovery disk.  Of course if your successful in repairing the installation is entirely another matter.  If current recovery environment isn't repairing the problem a Windows Recovery Disk is unlikely to be successful (again) exact same environment as the recovery environment that you already used and is contained on the Installation ISO

Comment: @Ramhound If I'm reading [this wiki page right](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10_version_history), my PC is actually already on 1703, the "Creator's Update"? Currently trying to create an install disk [via the instructions here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10).

Comment: Sorry; I meant upgrade your 1607 installations to 1703;

Comment: @Ramhound Seems like that isn't even necessary, the utility at the link in my prior comment will let you make the ISO or bootable USB. Got that far, now trying to coax my ancient PC into booting off a USB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I still don't know if making an *actual* repair disk from one of the laptops would have worked, but here is what ultimately allowed me to reinstall Windows on my broken PC:

1. I downloaded the [Windows 10 Installation Media Creation Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) from Microsoft on one of the working laptops.
2. Turns out you can use this tool on any OS version, upgrading the laptop wasn't required.
3. I ran the tool and chose "Create installation media for another PC".
4. I originally created a boot USB, but my very old PC had trouble booting from it, [I'm not the only one that has had this problem](https://superuser.com/questions/1017950/unable-to-boot-windows-10-installer-from-an-original-usb-thumb-drive).
5. I went back and, using the same tool, instead burned a DVD of the Windows 10 Install ISO.
6. Booted my old PC from the DVD.
7. Reinstalled Windows from scratch. Fresh install, no apps, but at least I can get to all my old data.